# How to make a .jar open using a specific jdk?

Tags: java, jar, macos-sierra, java-8

I've ran into an issue. I'm running on macOS Sierra (10.12.1). This .jar file I downloaded requires a JDK. So, I installed JDK8 (jdk180121). I was able to extract JDK8 .pkg without typing in my password (authenticate).  I then tried to place the new folder into the proper place. However, it asks me to authenticate the JDK (aka asks for the password). I do not want to give my password, so, therefore, I can't place it in the proper location. However, I still need to open the .jar file I mentioned earlier. **How can I point the .jar file to where the JDK8 is located?**

OSX: 10.12.2
JDK: jdk180121
.jar: craftbukkit-1.11.2(.jar)

Comment: Javascript is not Java. Your question's a bit unclear. Is the question on just how to run a jar? Or does running the jar ask for your credentials?

Comment: I know JS isnt Java but I didn't know which it would fall under. The question is, how do I run a .jar file using a specific path to my JDK since my JDK isnt under the proper location

Comment: Well considering this question is purely about Java, which do you think it should fall under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch with a specific JRE (You wouldn't need the JDK to just run an application) you can do it through the command line.

Open a terminal and navigate to the directory with the Java binary and launch this way:

`java -jar path/to/jar/program.jar`

Comment: I do need the JDK because its a java developing app

Comment: Your question is too vague then. What's this mystery application? You run Java apps with the JRE, not the JDK. If it's Bukkit, [development is done in an IDE](http://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Setting_Up_Your_Workspace) like Eclipse, IntelliJ, or Netbeans. You would launch Eclipse, for example, and point Eclipse to the JDK.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a ton man! You read my mind on the Bukkit thing! Eclipse wouldn't work but IntelliJ worked out for me now I just have to learn how to use it! Lol thanks man!

Comment: Sure thing. If it helped, give an upvote and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://www.jbang.dev/

```
jbang -j=8 path/to/jar/program.jar
```